# Objective: Create Staff Turnover Report from scratch

Tags: sql, database-design, reporting-services, crystal-reports, data-warehouse

I have a requirement to create staff turnover report that should display following information according to parameterized period:

1. current staff
2. starters
3. leavers
4. manager
5. contracted site

Currently, I have a few ideas how to get a report. Either create slowly changing dimension or copy snapshots of employees table for each period or track starter and leavers seperately for each payrun. I have tried slowly changing dimension and it did fine job on new starters; however, it failed on leavers. I am not sure if tracking starters and leaver for each payruns would work.

**Created a table below as a start of solution**

I am relatively new in MS SQL 2008 business. Please adise. The main goal is to identify managers and contracted sites with highest staff turnover.

**Notes**
-Currently, I am not using any specific techonlogy and looking for solution.

-I do intend to build and design a brand new database for the sake of the report. By *database* I mean a few collection of tables that sit on CRM database (SQL 2008). By *Collection of tables* I mean "dimension" table for managers, "dimension" table of contracted sites, and a table of staff. So currently, I think that my solution should have at least 3 tables; however, my skills are not that good to solve the puzzle.

I think that have tables above would let me to write a SQL query that could compare different periods and get required results.

payno   depcod  Idd Imported

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001A 31 December 2011

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001B 31 December 2011

16822   EDE322001   16822EDE322001A 31 December 2011

17694   EDE322001   17694EDE322001A 31 December 2011

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001A 04 January 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001B 04 January 2012

16822   EDE322001   16822EDE322001A 04 January 2012

17694   EDE322001   17694EDE322001A 04 January 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001A 31 January 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001B 31 January 2012

16822   EDE322001   16822EDE322001A 31 January 2012

17694   EDE322001   17694EDE322001A 31 January 2012

17661   EDE322001   17661EDE322001A 31 January 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001A 01 February 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001B 01 February 2012

16822   EDE322001   16822EDE322001A 01 February 2012

17906   EDE322001   17906EDE322001A 01 February 2012

17907   EDE322001   17907EDE322001A 01 February 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001A 29 February 2012

12568   EDE322001   12568EDE322001B 29 February 2012

17907   EDE322001   17907EDE322001A 29 February 2012

Table above is table of snapshots. Snapshot date is displayed in Imported Column. ( Applogoes for messy table; I could not figure out how to make a table) Now i need to find a away how to compare one date to another (ideally in the loop) to figure out the difference between 1st date and following date.

For instance, 17661    EDE322001   17661EDE322001A 31 January 2012 is a new staff and 16822    EDE322001   16822EDE322001A 01 February 2012 is a leaver.

Many thanks

Comment: At the moment, this question is rather open-ended. Can you amend it to be more specific? Additionally, it isn't clear whether you are using a specific data-warehousing methodology (although the rreference to SCDs sounds specific to Kimball), nor how you represented employees in your SCD (there are at least three different types of SCD in the Kimball methodology).

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply. I have used historical SCD and only for testing purposes. I am looking for advice/solution which way to go to create report with requirements above. It is open ended question.

Comment: @TadasV please read the meta entries on open ended and wide ranging questions. As you're a newbie I'm loathe to mark this as unacceptably so.

Comment: In addition, pleas clarify whether you intend to design and build a brand new database for the sake of a single report.  Historically, databases deliver more bang for the buck when the data, once collected and organized, can be used for multiple purposes.

Comment: Thanks Walter for your comment. I intend to design a to z. Currently, I have no data for the report. however, I plan to restore historical payroll application and import it into DB for reporting perpuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be looking at this too simplistically given all the talk about slowly changing dimensions, etc, but what's wrong with a plain old bit of SQL? I'm going to assume you have an Employee table with Manager, ContractedSite, StartDate and EndDate fields.

You want the following:

- Current staff. Is this current at the start of the period or at the end of the period or active at some time during the period?
- Starters. People who have a StartDate greater than or equal to the start of the period but less than or equal to the end of the period.
- Leavers. People who have an EndDate greater than or equal to the start of the period but less than or equal to the end of the period.
- Turnover. Which brings us back to what you mean by "Current staff". Turnover is essentially the difference between the current staff at the start of the period and the current staff at the end of the period, expressed either as a raw number or a percentage. So current staff at the start of the period are people with a StartDate less than the period start and either no EndDate or an EndDate greater than or equal to the start of the period. Similarly with the current staff at the end of the period.

So you have some specific cases to extract from your data:

```
SELECT Manager, ContractedSite, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN StartDate < @PeriodStart AND ((EndDate IS NULL) OR (EndDate >= @PeriodStart)) THEN 1 END) AS OpeningStaff,
    SUM(CASE WHEN StartDate >= @PeriodStart AND StartDate <= @PeriodEnd THEN 1 END) AS Starters,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EndDate >= @PeriodStart AND EndDate <= @PeriodEnd) THEN 1 END) AS Leavers,
    SUM(CASE WHEN StartDate <= @PeriodEnd AND ((EndDate IS NULL) OR (EndDate > @PeriodEnd)) THEN 1 END) AS ClosingStaff
FROM Employee
WHERE (StartDate <= @PeriodEnd) AND ((EndDate IS NULL) OR (EndDate >= @PeriodStart))
GROUP BY Manager, ContractedSite
ORDER BY Manager, ContractedSite
```

Now you just need to calculate the difference between OpeningStaff and ClosingStaff in your report to get the turnover and you're done.

Comment: Yes, currently we are interested in count of leavers, startes and difference between them. The issue is that payroll system does not store leavers; therefore, there is no possiblity to trackthem. I should be able to use your query if/when I create a table with fields used.

Comment: You have a payroll system with no concept of a termination date for employees? That seems quite unusual. Or do you simply have a list of current employees?

Comment: Yes, we do have a list of current employees. If employee leaves then he goes to terminated list at the end of the Accounting Year. Before end of Accounting year, employee is listed with current employees; however, there are no jobs assigned. In general, there are three tables here: current employees, terminated employees, and currently employed.

Comment: Without a way of determining terminated employees, you can't calculate turnover. You could try to fudge it by saying that an employee with no jobs has been terminated but that has the problem that employees with no jobs this week but who get jobs next week aren't terminated, they may simply be between jobs or on holidays. I think you don't have enough data to calculate turnover accurately.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Currently, the best i idea/solution i have is to try import last ten payruns into single table and then to figure out some tsql code to compare separate fortnight with self join. In theory, i believe it could possible show me leavers/starters for 2 separate fortnights.